# Efficient way to compute Heteroscedasticity Robust standard errors in R

Tags: r, statistics, standards

I am trying to compute robust standard errors in R. I am aware of two solutions that do what I want, but are incredibly slow. Hence my questions is whether there's a way that is more efficient. E.g. something that has been coded up in Rcpp.

My context is that I am fitting a model with a large number of variables (fixed effects). I am however not interested in these coefficients, I only care about inference one single coefficient (that of X in the example below).

**Fast Solution**

???

**Slow Solution 1**

```
library(sandwich)
lmfe<-lm(Y ~ X + factor(strata_ids))
coeftest(lmfe, vcov = vcovHC(lmfe, "HC1"))
```

**Slow Solution 2**

The manual solution I got from [here](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/heteroskedasticity-robust-and-clustered-standard-errors-in-r/) is:

```
summaryw <- function(model) {
  s <- summary(model)
  X <- model.matrix(model)
  u2 <- residuals(model)^2
  XDX <- 0

  ## Here one needs to calculate X'DX. But due to the fact that
  ## D is huge (NxN), it is better to do it with a cycle.
  for(i in 1:nrow(X)) {
    XDX <- XDX + u2[i]*X[i,]%*%t(X[i,])
  }

  # inverse(X'X)
  XX1 <- solve(t(X)%*%X)

  # Variance calculation (Bread x meat x Bread)
  varcovar <- XX1 %*% XDX %*% XX1

  # degrees of freedom adjustment
  dfc <- sqrt(nrow(X))/sqrt(nrow(X)-ncol(X))

  # Standard errors of the coefficient estimates are the
  # square roots of the diagonal elements
  stdh <- dfc*sqrt(diag(varcovar))

  t <- model$coefficients/stdh
  p <- 2*pnorm(-abs(t))
  results <- cbind(model$coefficients, stdh, t, p)
  dimnames(results) <- dimnames(s$coefficients)
  results
}
```

Comment: I'd model the strata IDs as a random effect. You seem to have the kind of textbook example for which mixed-effects models have been developed.

Comment: Thanks, but I have strong reasons to use fixed effects

Comment: Well, then you do over-fitting with a huge design matrix. And that's slow. You might be able to make it faster, but beware of omitting checks for singularities and such.

Comment: You could also check out the `lfe` package which is built to handle large numbers of fixed effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question already has one good answer (i.e. use `lfe::felm()`).

For an even faster method, try the new [**fixest**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html) package. Using the OPs example,

```r
library(fixest)
mod = feols(Y ~ X | strata_ids, data = dat)

## SEs are automatically clustered by the strata_ids FE
mod

## We can compute other SEs on the fly with summary.fixest(), e.g.
summary(mod, se = 'standard') ## vanilla
summary(mod, se = 'white') ## HC
# etc
```

The more general lesson is to avoid modeling fixed-effects as factors in R... or any other language TBH. This is equivalent to the DV approach and will always be slow. Instead, you'll want to use a use a purpose-built package that leverages [FWL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem) or some other optimised estimation method.